# How can I push data into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, push

I have pushed some data into an array:

```
if(target === 'create'){
    if(name === 'form[username]' || name === 'form[name]' || name === 'form[slug]' || name === 'form[plainPassword]'){
        errors.push(name);
    }
} else {
    if(name === 'form[username]' || name === 'form[name]' || name === 'form[slug]' ){
        errors.push(name);
    }
}
```

It actually works fine. But it seems to me that it is really too much repeating code, but I still cannot find a way to reduce the code, or make a simpler better solution.

Comment: are you talking about **errors** array or **form[]** ?

Comment: about errors array

Comment: looking at this tiny piece of code that you have shown doesn't need any optimization.

Comment: @Dhiren Indeed, In fact, it could be shorter but it's just an if/else that cost nothing in programming languages. So there is no need to be optimized

Comment: @ColinCline correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I rigth understand you, you want to simplify your statements. From my perspective it could be like this:

```
if(name === 'form[username]' || name === 'form[name]' || name === 'form[slug]' 
                             || (name === 'form[plainPassword]' && target === 'create')){
    errors.push(name);
}
```

Since:

```
name === 'form[username]' || name === 'form[name]' || name === 'form[slug]'
```

is repeated two times, it doesn't matter if `target === 'create'` is true or false for this statements.

In fact just add `(name === 'form[plainPassword]' && target === 'create')` to if statement and that's all

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in two methods

```
function CheckErrors(target,name){
   switch(target){
     case 'create':
       SaveError(name,true);
       break;
     default:
       SaveError(name);
       break;
    }
}

function SaveError(name,checkPassword){
     if(name === 'form[username]' || name === 'form[name]' || name === 'form[slug]' ||(checkPassword && name === 'form[plainPassword]')){
        errors.push(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you missed something

Comment: just trying to figure out what i missed :)

Comment: OP dont want to push 'form[plainPassword]' in else statement

Comment: indeed i see it. If i had to re-write it would still look ugly

Answer (score 2):

You could use arrays to simplify your if statement:

```
if((target === 'create' && name === 'form[plainPassword]') || ['form[username]', 'form[name]', 'form[slug]'].includes(name)){
  errors.push(name);
}
```